# Calling was_published_today django 1.6

Tags: python, django, datetime

There's something I'm fundamentally missing I think from the way django handles "today." I'm running through the Django 1.6 tutorial, and a method that appears to be in earlier versions of django doesn't seem to work here.

```
def was_published_today(self):
    return (self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today())
```

This returns false even if creating a poll today. I also tried this

```
def today(self):
    return datetime.date.today()

def was_published_today(self):
    return self.pub_date.date() == self.today()
```

That didn't work either though. Running through the counsel I verified that I'm getting the correct date for datetime.date.today, so I'm not sure why I can't get it to work right. What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Can you make your title a bit more clear?

Comment: Sorry didn't realize I messed up the tile there.

Comment: And `pub_date` is ... ?

Comment: Today? I always make a new one to test this.